# Transforming $|100\rangle$ state into $|000\rangle + |111\rangle$ state using only Hadamard and CNOT gates

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, entanglement, hadamard, quantum-circuit

[image]

Hi, How to convert $|100\rangle$ 3-qubit quantum state into $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle + |111\rangle)$ state using only Hadamard and CNOT gates? Also, is output state an entangled one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first qubit is in state $|1\rangle$, i.e. the input state $|100\rangle$ then resulting GHZ state is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle - |111\rangle)$, i.e. the phase is $\pi$. To have phase $0$, $Z$ has to be applied but this gate is not allowed. But you can use controlled $Z$ which is composed only with $H$ and  $CNOT$. The circuit is this

[image]

A part before orange line produces the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle - |111\rangle)$ from $|100\rangle$, a part after the line is controlled $Z$.

Here is a resulting state from IBM Q:

[image]

As you can see, the phase is correct.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The upper figure shows the quantum circuit to do so, the first $X$ gate is to let the first qubit be in the $|1\rangle$ state coherently.

The state $\frac{|000\rangle+|111\rangle}{\sqrt2}$ is the GHZ state, it is one of the most famous tri-qubit entangled state (another one is the W state), you may see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state) for detail.

Comment: Hi Yitian, the circuit above produces |000>-|111>, but, I need |000>+|111> state. Phase is incorrect. I understand the confusion, considering you're viewing only probabilities. So, how to generate |000>+|111> ??

Comment: Note that $X$ gate is forbidden, only H and CNOT are allowed.

Comment: @MartinVesely, Yitian has used X just to flip q0 to make the 3-qubit state |100> to begin with. So, Yitian hasn't used X in actual circuit.

Comment: @Sscr: Ah, I see. But still there is a problem with the phase. See my answer for the solution :-) But still +1.

Comment: Notice that if the X gate were allowed then it is very simple.... all you have to do is to bit flip the qubit to get it back to the state $|00\cdots 0\rangle$ and generate the GHZ states from there..

Comment: @KAJ226 Yes I agree!

Comment: Also if the Z gate is available then you don't have to do controlled Z either... you just need to apply the $Z$ gate to the top qubit to fix the phase. But without the Z gate, @MartinVesely is right! +1

Comment: Yes, I forget the phase...

Comment: @KAJ226: It seems to me that this is a logic behind the excercise, to find implementation of a circuit with limited gate set. Everything is more or less simple if you can use for example U3 gate from IBM Q or x, y and z rotations...

Comment: @MartinVesely You are absolutely correct. I just made my comments in a general setting... nothing more. :)